# Why Picasso debug mode doesn't work?

Tags: android, picasso

Could anybody tell me, please, why Picasso doesn't indicate debugging? 
I have following code:

```
Picasso.with(MyActivity.this.getApplicationContext()).setDebugging(true);
Picasso.with(MyActivity.this.getApplicationContext()).load(message).into(imageView);
```

And no indication at left-top corner of picture. In the same time, debugging mode works fine in same application with same context (but for different images). Small ones 150x150 are indicated, but large ones (1400x1400) are not. Does the size of images has matter? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Changed to `setIndicatorsEnabled(true);`

DEBUG INDICATORS

For development you can enable the display of a colored ribbon which indicates the image source. Call setIndicatorsEnabled(true) on the Picasso instance.

Reference : http://square.github.io/picasso/

**Ex:**

```
Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(context);
picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
//do other stuff
picasso.load(xxx).into(imageView);
```

Comment: You can also use picasso.setLoggingEnabled(true) to enable logs in LogCat

Answer (score 6):

It works in large images too, but because the resolution of the images are large, you can't see the triangles.

Comment: you are right. In my case large images were rescaled by layout to fit the screen and yellow triangles simply became invisible. Thank you.

Comment: We might need a confirm on this from Jake Wharton. Actually after resizing the pictures the indicators showed up for me as well. Thx @2ku

Answer (score 4):

now, changed to:

```
sPicasso.setLoggingEnabled(true);
```

PICASSO_VERSION=2.5.2